# Error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Tags: c#

In my c# program I have this first line:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;


private const string TargetUrl = "http://www.TEST.com";
private const string TorAppLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\test\Lis\lis.exe";
private static readonly string[] InstalledBrowsers
    = new[]{"IExplore","Chrome","Firefox","Safari"};

static private Process _prc;

static private int _reqCounter = 0;
...
```

When I compile it returns error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.

How can I solve it?

Comment: it says it wants a class, delegate, enum interface or struct; that is a big hint, because *fields etc must be defined inside a class or struct*

Comment: The only meaningful answer to this question would be a complete tutorial explaining how OOP and C# works, making it too broad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please define your const and member field inside your class

```
class Program
    {

        private const string TargetUrl = "http://www.TEST.com";
        private const string TorAppLocation = @"C:\Program File (x86)\test\Lis\lis.exe";
        private static readonly string[] InstalledBrowsers
        = new[]{"IExplore","Chrome","Firefox","Safari"};

        static private Process _prc;

        static private int _reqCounter = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           //code here
        } 
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot to define your const and other fields inside a class.

**EDIT :**

```
class Whatever { 

    private const string TargetUrl = "http://www.TEST.com";
    private const string TorAppLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\test\Lis\lis.exe";
    private static readonly string[] InstalledBrowsers = new[]{"IExplore","Chrome","Firefox","Safari"};

    static private Process _prc;

    static private int _reqCounter = 0;

}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need the code to be executed at the very beginning of the program

Comment: @almal that is completely unrelated; just put them in whatever class it is that declares `Main()` (often called `Program`, but doesn't need to be). But frankly, IMO "at the very beginning of the program" means *inside* the `Main()` method